# How to make PhpStorm recognize Laravel aliases?

Tags: laravel, phpstorm

The Laravel package comes with an `aliases` array in [config/app.php](https://github.com/laravel/laravel/blob/f0de9fd9967d4e1b4427d8458bf8983bc2cde201/config/app.php#L191)

Essentially, it allows to import shorter namespaces at the start of your document.

For example, I can import the `Illuminate\Support\Facades\DB::class` class just by `DB`:

```
<?php 

namespace App\Services\Whatever;

use DB;
```

However, this generates a warning in my PhpStorm editor

> Warning:(4,5) Undefined class 'DB'

Is there a way to make PhpStorm aware of the aliases? Or am I forced to not use the Laravel aliases in order to resolve those IDE warnings?

Comment: 1) Laravel IDE Helper package. https://github.com/barryvdh/laravel-ide-helper 2) AFAIK Laravel 8 examples in their Documentation (https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/routing#basic-routing) prefer using an explicit import of the actual Facade class and not just `Route` out of the blue like in previous versions.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try to copy this file to the root folder of your laravel project:

https://gist.github.com/barryvdh/5227822

Comment: It would be better to use the root package this gist is generated from: https://github.com/barryvdh/laravel-ide-helper

Answer (score 0):

To add to galloleonardo's answer, I had an issue where after adding the _ide_helper.php file, I started getting the "Multiple Definitions Exist for class DB" error.  Deleting the empty class definitions in the _ide_helper.php file cleared up the error, although I'm not sure what the long term effects are.

Searched for "class DB" in _ide_helper.php and remove the empty entry.